# java.text.MessageFormat increase decimal places precision for BigDecimal / Number

Tags: java, formatting, bigdecimal, messageformat

I am using `java.text.MessageFormat`to replace place holders in a template that displays price per unit. Following is the piece of code that does it.

```
public String format(Object[] arguments, String pattern) {
    MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat("");
    formatter.applyPattern(pattern);
    return formatter.format(arguments);
}
```

`pattern` is

> {0} {1} per {2}

and `arguments` are

> argument[0] = "USD", argument[1] = BigDecimal(0.0002), argument[2] = "shirt"

I expected the formatter to output

> "USD 0.0002 per shirt"

But formatter is reducing the precision and produces

> "USD 0 per shirt"

It looks like `MessageFormat` is considering just 3 digits after the decimal point. "BigDecimal(0.01)" works as expected.

So is there any property I can tweak to tell the `MessageFormat` it should use a certain precision? Changing the `pattern` is not an option for me.

I can convert the argument to `String` from `BigDecimal` before formatting. But that will be my last option.

**EDIT:**
The limit of 3 decimal points comes from `NumberFormat`.

```
private int    maximumFractionDigits = 3;
```

is there a way we can change this value and make MessageFormat use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use formats such as `{0,number,#.##}` in the pattern.
The Javadoc of [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) has more details if you're interested.

Since you cannot change the pattern, converting the objects to string before-hand would be the only solution though

EDIT: actually I did not realize that the formats could be set programmatically:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] argument = new Object[3];
    argument[0] = "USD";
    argument[1] = new BigDecimal(0.0002);
    argument[2] = "shirt";

    System.out.println(format(argument, "{0} {1} per {2}"));
}

public static String format(Object[] arguments, String pattern) {
    MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat(pattern);

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(7);

    for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] instanceof BigDecimal) {
            formatter.setFormat(i, nf);
        }
    }

    return formatter.format(arguments);
}
```

This should print: `USD 0.0002 per shirt`

Comment: By converting the objects to string before-hand, I not only have to change the code in a lot of places, but also will lose the default number formatting provided

Comment: I see, I suppose you can use the class of the arguments to apply the format, see my edited answer

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for